# Longest subsequence with elements greater than its length

Tags: arrays, dynamic

Given an array of n elements, find the longest subsequence of k (k<=n) elements which contain only elements greater than or equal to k.

For example:

```
Array: [3, 1, 5, 1, 6]
Output: 3 (the subsequence 3, 5, 6 meets the requirements 
because 3,5,6 are all greater than 3.)
```

How can I do this in O(n)?

I tried my best, but all I can come up with is O(n logn).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also note that `3` is *not* greater than `3`. Perhaps you mean greater *or equal to*?